# is it really this easy to create an ng service with observable functions?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

The following url seems to provide a pretty good overview of implementing REST through ng services:

https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/02/01/consuming-a-rest-api-with-angular-http-service-in-typescript

Is it really this easy to create an ng service with observable functions?  It looks like all you need to do is include the following line at the top of the service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Then every function in the class automatically becomes an observable.  Is it really this easy?

Comment: What's your issue? Observable is just a data type like any other data type.

Comment: angular http library returns observables, that's it. The Observable import is for the typings I think. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Importing Observable from rxjs library will import Observable binding that is exported by this module making it **"usable"** in your code. In other words you will be able to use Observable in this specific code block. It won't *magically* transform all functions to Observable functions. Let me provide you an example.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class DummyService {

  constructor() { }

  regularFunction(): string[] {
    let data: string[];
    // Logic here
    return data;
  }
  // This function returns an array of strings

  observableFunction(): Observable<string[]> {
    let data: string[];
    // Logic here
    return Observable.of(data);
  }
  // This function returns an Observable array of strings

}
```

Notice here that i am importing `of` from rxjs as well. Make sure to import all the functions / properties / objects that you use from rxjs library, else you'll get errors during the compilation process.

So to sum up, importing something won't transform anything at it's own, it will just make that something ***reachable / usable*** in your code.

One more thing to point out after checking the url you have posted, is that by default, an Http request (post, get etc) using HttpClient from angular will always return Observable data.

```
public getData<data>(): Observable<data> {
   return this.http.get<data>('https://www.example.com/data');
}
```

In order to use that data you need to subscribe to that Observable.

```
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
  // Code Logic Here
});
```

I hope that i helped you. Cheers